# Mariadb MyRocks Update Statement Lose Data

Tags: mariadb

**Summary**

- I have table **location** with fields: device_id, unix_time
- I use an update statement from device_id "1000002912" to "1234567890"
- And I have **not found data** for device_id "1234567890" also "1000002912"

**Environment**:

- Mariadb 10.10.2-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server on Centos 7
- Engine: MyRocks

**Reproduce**

**Step 1**: Set variable rocksdb_bulk_load to update many data

```
set session rocksdb_bulk_load=1;
```

**Step 2**: Change device_id from "1000002912" to "1234567890"

```
update location set device_id="1234567890" where device_id="1000002912" and unix_time between 1682355600 and 1682355600 + 86400

Query OK, 30786 rows affected (2,009 sec)
Rows matched: 30786  Changed: 30786  Warnings: 0
```

**Step 3**: Query data of new device_id

```
select count(*) from location where device_id="1234567890" and unix_time between 1682355600 and 1682355600 + 86400

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,792 sec)
```

**Step 4**: Query data of old device_id

```
select count(*) from location where device_id="1000002912" and unix_time between 1682355600 and 1682355600 + 86400

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,229 sec)
```

[image: Capture Summary]

**show create table location**

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| location | CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `unix_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `device_id` (`device_id`,`unix_time`),
  KEY `unix_time` (`unix_time`)
) ENGINE=ROCKSDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4407998942 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image, please!) output of `show create table location`

Comment: when I tried this on 11.0.1, I saw it not find anything for the new id but it did find for the old id.   starting a new session showed the data with the old id, but trying the update again failed with a spurious duplicate key error.  do you need to use rocksdb_bulk_load?  seems like that is somehow buggy (unless it's just rocksdb in general)

Comment: do you really want device_id to be utf8mb3?  I did see a warning from create table because of that

Comment: @ysth , yeap, i need rocksdb_bulk_load for update large rows data. I do not really use utf8mb3, I use the default charset. When creating table, I do not see any warning.

Comment: Given that this seems like a bug, you might try upgrading to 10.11.2, or at least 10.10.3.  10.11 is a long term support release, and likely what you want to be on anyway.

Comment: oh, duh.  given that I'm seeing a similar problem on 11.0.1, it's very unlikely to be fixed in 10.11.2 or 10.10.3, which are a little older I think

Comment: Also to get bugs fix, stack overflow disclosure isn't enough, report directly to [the MariaDB server bug tracker](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: I add an issue at: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31131